# (HTML, CSS) How to link to and re-use a block of code that comes from a single HTML file source, like a template that "extends"?

Tags: html, css

Sorry that I'm using odd jargon for explaining my question. I'm not sure what the terminology is for what I'm trying to do, and googling has not led me very far yet, so I was hoping that someone could help clear up my inexperience.

I have a localhost wiki that I code and update regularly for myself, and it's meant to be entirely linked together with a persistent sidebar. However, I have to manually edit EVERY .html file's sidebar code when I add a page or make a "global" change, and I'm heavily violating the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) rule by doing this. I have some experience with Django and it kind of solves this problem by using templates and extends, but I haven't found an equivalent solution for a locally hosted (I WANT to host it on my network soon, but I haven't gotten that far with it yet), vanilla basic HTML/CSS/JS group of files.

So, in short, the problem I'm trying to solve is that I want to extend certain global HTML elements and CSS elements to all pages/files contained within this project, and eliminate the duplicate code that I'm using in the transition.

Here is some of the code I'm (unnecessarily, I think) repeating within every HTML document of my wiki.

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-item-container">
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="html_info.html">HTML</a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="css_info.html">CSS</a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="javascript_info.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="misc.html">Misc</a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="python.html">Python</a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="sample.html">Sample</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to remove this block of code from each individual html file and replace it with something like

```
extend sidebar code from template.html
```

...However that would work. Would anyone be willing to share some insight with me on this? Thank you! I would also greatly appreciate it if you could tell me the jargon around the concept I'm trying to describe. I thought it was called templating and extending, but searching for that hasn't led me anywhere useful unfortunately.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components or something like https://reactjs.org/ or https://vuejs.org/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template to add the frozen's comment